# How to log Windows username from local --> target server, logged in /var/log/secure?

Tags: linux, rhel

How do I enable windows username (ie. the remote username) from which we have logged in the target Linux server, to be recorded in the log entry in `/var/log/secure`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you're asking. The Window's username does not get passed to the Linux system in any meaningful way where you'd be able to parse it and store it in a log file. The only username that you can log is the username that was used to log into the Linux system.

Beyond this you could log the IP address that the login attempt was initiated from using the `w` command.

Example:

```
$ w -i
 21:14:08 up 2 days, 19:50,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
vagrant  pts/0    10.0.2.2         Sat20    0.00s  2.09s  0.01s sshd: vagrant [priv]
```

Here you can see that someone logged into the `vagrant` account from the IP address 10.0.2.2, via `ssh`. Keep in mind that SSHD already logs similar info:

```
Jul 16 00:15:05 centos7 sshd[31577]: Accepted publickey for vagrant from 10.0.2.2 port 58471 ssh2: RSA SHA25
6:1vJymfZsu2KZ49lDftGMzz2VEb2Z2Y8PNi9cs55eHGE
Jul 16 00:15:05 centos7 sshd[31577]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user vagrant by (uid=0)
```